Why is CMake locating incorrect package when building once, but finds the correct location when building again? [Windows, C++]
I have a small C++ program that uses an external library fmt located at the location C:\msys64\ucrt64\include\fmt.
I build my program using cmake:
mkdir build1
cd build1
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
mingw32-make

It worked correctly, and located the fmt package in the correct location.
However, when building it again, I encountered an issue:
> mingw32-make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/single_main_particles.cpp.obj
[100%] Linking CXX executable main.exe
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\main.dir/objects.a(single_main_particles.cpp.obj):single_main_particles.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `__imp__ZN3fmt2v97vformatB5cxx11ENS0_17basic_string_viewIcEENS0_17basic_format_argsINS0_20basic_format_contextINS0_8appenderEcEEEE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\main.dir\build.make:100: main.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2

This seems to be because, this time, cmake has located fmt from a different location. I found this through CMakeCache.txt:
fmt_DIR:PATH=C:/Users/<User-Name>/anaconda3/Library/lib/cmake/fmt`

previously this path was:
fmt_DIR:PATH=fmt_DIR:PATH=C:/msys64/ucrt64/lib/cmake/fmt

The version I am using is cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11). But I think it changes to 3.29 when building. Which is okay, but I still thought of pointing it out, since from other posts I thought that older versions can lead to different problems too:
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=29
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=3

My question is: why did cmake behave differently this time.
My doubts are on the build command:
cmake .. -G "MinGW Makefiles"
that I may have done something differently before that I don't remember.
Moreoever, how can I control this behaviour such that cmake can locate the correct path every time?
Below is my CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(Particles_Project)

add_executable(main single_main_particles.cpp)

find_package(fmt)
target_link_libraries(main fmt::fmt)

It's only a single .cpp file because I wanted to try cmake on a simple case without src and  include.

The prefixes where CMake searches the package configuration file (in your case, for the package fmt) are described in the documentation (the list is stared at "The set of installation prefixes is constructed using the following steps."). As you could see, prefixes are taken from several environment variables. Probably, some of those variables have been changed in the environment where you calls cmake. Or you have environment variables which are checked only in recent CMake versions.

Are you building from within an anaconda environment? Do you have environment variables set which contain the anaconda directory?

For force CMake to locate a specific package from several available, you could set fmt_ROOT variable, or use any other hint listed in the documentation for find_package.

@AlanBirtles yes, I just noticed that is an issue. If I don't build from the anaconda environment then it build in the desired way and find the correct path for the fmt. I think the easier solution would be to deactivate the anaconda environment.
